# using sklearn KMeans with initial centroids without fitting model

Tags: python, json, scikit-learn, k-means, jsonlines

I have fitted a KMeans model and retrived the centroid for the data.

Is there any way that I can use the predict() function using these centroids to initalise the KMeans model but **without calling the fit function**

I tried to run the following code and ran into this error.
Here the jsonl file has a json object as

```
{ "primary" : [[<some_array>]]}
{ "secondary" : [[<some_array>]]}
```

```
models = dict()
for json_str in json_list:
    result = json.loads(json_str)
    models[list(result.keys())[0]] = list(result.values())[0]


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k = KMeans(init = np.array(models['primary']))
k.predict(inference_data)
```

```
NotFittedError: This KMeans instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

This problem is well handeled in cuml version of KMeans but how to get it done with sklearn.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize the object. You can use either [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). [Sklearn's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html) preferred way is to use `joblib`.

```
from joblib import dump, load

k = KMeans()

# fit and stuff here

dump(k, 'filename.joblib')

# later on

k = load('filename.joblib')
```

As for setting values on the object like you're asking, you could try setting all of the [attributes that K-means defines after fitting](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb24/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L1457). You'd have to save all of this data yourself though and using `pickle` or `joblib` is easier.

Psuedo code below. Everything on the right of the equals sign would have to be saved.

```
k = KMeans.__new__(KMeans)

k.cluster_centers_ = best_centers
k._n_features_out = self.cluster_centers_.shape[0]
k.labels_ = best_labels
k.inertia_ = best_inertia
k.n_iter_ = best_n_iter
```