# Using sklearn KMeans without fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

Similarly to the question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909643/using-sklearn-kmeans-with-initial-centroids-without-fitting-model), I want to cluster some data according to pre-computed centroids. Differently by that question, these centroids are are provided by other methods.

I could compute it myself, but using the interface of scikit-learn's KMeans is extremely useful for other operation (e.g. labels points and sample points later).

Basically, is there a workaround to use KMean with `max_iter=0` and `n_init=0`?

Comment: Maybe something like this could work: given `X` being the data and `centroids` the provided initialization, `km = KMeans(n_clusters=centroids.shape[0])` ,  `km.cluster_centers_ = centroids` `km._n_threads = 1`, `labels = km.predict(X)`

Answer (score 3):

KMeans in scikit-learn [accepts a **callable** as an initializer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

> init{‘k-means++’, ‘random’}, callable or array-like of shape
> (n_clusters, n_features), default=’k-means++’ Method for
> initialization:
>
> ‘k-means++’ : selects initial cluster centroids using sampling based
> on an empirical probability distribution of the points’ contribution
> to the overall inertia. This technique speeds up convergence. The
> algorithm implemented is “greedy k-means++”. It differs from the
> vanilla k-means++ by making several trials at each sampling step and
> choosing the best centroid among them.
>
> ‘random’: choose n_clusters observations (rows) at random from data
> for the initial centroids.
>
> If an array is passed, it should be of shape (n_clusters, n_features)
> and gives the initial centers.
>
> If a callable is passed, it should take arguments X, n_clusters and a
> random state and return an initialization.

So you can just do

```
def custom_fun(X, n_clusters, random_state):
   ...

kmeans = Kmeans(init=custom_fun)
```

and then set `max_iters=0`

since sklearn does parameters checks and max_iters

```
import sklearn
sklearn.set_config(
   skip_parameter_validation=True,  
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I still have the error `The 'max_iter' parameter of KMeans must be an int in the range [1, inf). Got 0 instead.` Could you please complete your question? What should I write inside the function?

Comment: see an update (you need to disable these  checks)